# How to complete login with phonegap and devise (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, jquery-mobile, cordova, backbone.js

I have a rails app that has devise gem installed (with auth_token setup). I'm not sure how to make my jquery mobile app ask for the token and store it (in a secure way).
Thanks!

Comment: hi did you ever find out this answer to this, I'm trying to do the same thing but I can't find any info about where to get started. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i'm also curious what the solution is to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

i have a similar set up - rails 3 backend with devise as the authentication. i'm using standard jquery, though, on a full browser instead of a mobile, and i have my users log in through normal html forms.

in order to keep my users authenticated and be able to make backbone / jquery ajax calls back to my server, i had to add this to my rails.js file:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  }
});
```

once i put that in place, i didn't have to worry about authentication anymore.

hope that helps

Comment: Your solution is necessary when Rails is protecting against cross-site request forgery: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf But that's different than user authentication. I imagine Devise is actually setting a session cookie (with the help of Rails) and this lives on in your PhoneGap browser.

Comment: @DrewDara-Abrams are you sure that phonegap supports cookies?